# Postgres connection string CA keyword

Tags: postgresql, odbc

Can anybody enlighten me on the meaning of the CA keyword in ODBC connection string used for our Postgres database ? Driver is Postgres SQL Unicode

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config-opt.html), that is an abbreviation for `SSLmode`, and according to [the source](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git;a=blob;f=dlg_specific.h#l175), the possible values are the same as for `libpq` parameter [`sslmode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-SSLMODE).